# What is the field on engineering that combines chemistry and electronics together?

Tags: electrical-engineering, chemistry

I am looking for a career advice as I am interested in chemistry and electronics at the same time but the universities somehow have the two as different major. Is there any branch of engineering that combines the two?

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean when you say you are interested in "electronics"?

Comment: electronics as in programing micro controller and devices that uses chemistry in computing such as electro gel etc.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow either Chemistry (Science), Chemical Engineering or Electrical Engineering and purse a career in Semiconductors. There are many variation in Semiconductor that fall either into chemistry or electronics. Below is small sample of options

- [Semiconductor Lithography Systems](https://www.nikon.com/about/technology/product/semiconductor/index.htm#:%7E:text=A%20semiconductor%20lithography%20system%20undertakes,substrate%20known%20as%20a%20wafer.)
- [MEMS Technology](https://www.mouser.com/applications/mems-technology/)
- [Semiconductor Failure Analysis](https://eesemi.com/fa-techniques.htm)
- [Silicon Wafer Processing](https://www.waferworld.com/silicon-wafer-processing-how/#:%7E:text=Reduction,takes%20six%20to%20eight%20hours)
- [Microfluidics and microfluidic devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfluidics)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE. Since your interest pertains to do very distinct field, I would recommend in taking one field as a major and the other as minor with key subjects you are interested in. Electro-Chemistry is maybe you are interested in so check with the university program that if they offer it.

Comment: Electrochemistry is a pretty niche field so it's unlikely that will be offered as a major. Materials science is a close hybrid but the amount of Matsci jobs relative to matsci degree holders is very low so if you intend on using your degree that's probably not your best move. Research what jobs sound interesting to you and see what the required degrees are. Getting a ChemE or EE major with the other as a minor is much more marketable and practical, although they are two of the harder engineering disciplines.

Comment: yes, I totally agree.